# Tire vibration - pressure and brand

Tags: tires

The question is the about the effect of air pressure and brand on tire vibration (also known as wheel vibration).

Do we have less vibration when the air pressure is low or high ?

Aslo, does the brand of the tire affect vibration ? Which brands are considered to cause less vibratrion ?

Comment: I'd say this differs based on how well the wheel is balanced. That completely outshadows any tire brand or pressure related differences. You can have the same brand of tire either well or poorly balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clear a point before starting,

We cannot blame the Tyre  alone for vibration. Since there are lot of moving parts in cars.
They do have a good amount of contribution.

*Now, Let me try answering your question,*

**Does Air pressure be a cause for vibration,**

Yes, Both Low pressure and High Pressure cause vibrations. 
The tire pressure plays a major role it but note here tires are interlinked to many components 
such as Rims, wheel hubs, axle , suspension,brakes etc, So judgment should be liberal in this case.

Lets break down this topic to smaller piece,

Each tire type has precised tire pressure labeled on it so that it could perform optimally. 
The air pressure should also be kept at a level which not only keeps the structure of the tire strong,but also includes some flexibility smoother bumps.

**Low pressure:**

Low pressure in tires create more contact area in the road sacrificing the tire's structure. 
Due to the changing mass of the car and shifting mass distribution it can be worse in handling as the structure shifting wouldn't be much faster as your car moves. 
Also your weight shits to the the low pressure zone creating much pressure in tire.
That is why it become harder to steer the vehicle when the air is low. 
Driving low on air pressures could even damage your tires walls. And its not recommended.

**High Pressure:**

High Pressure tires can be compared to rock tires. Generally tires does some damping before it transfer to the suspension. So that's 
why you notice the sensitivity of the chip-lets while you drive when the pressure's are high. 
The reason why car topples on high speed is because tires looses its ability to shift the structure shape or we can say that it don't have the flexibility 
to cope with the speed.

Only tires cannot be blamed for this reason. There are numerous other factors contributing to it.

Air in the tire play a major role as other components in the vehicle do. We often do ignore that. Because after it something that holds 
your vehicle mass weight.

**Practical Understanding:**
To better understand functioning of tire, take your car to a slop. Halt your car in such way that it should pick pace, turn off your engine, try to steer, it would be damn hard. 
Try doing the same when the car is moving. 
You will get the raw understanding of the scenarios how hard and easy was to steer when your car was unpressurized and over-pressured. 
**or** 
Tell someone to push the car and you steer it with engines off.

**Note: Modern cars brakes don't work when engine turned off. Keep and on Parking brake/ Hand brake for emergency.**

And regarding your other questions, I cannot answer  it because choosing tires for vehicles is difficult part. 
That depends on many criteria, just try check boxing the below fields and go for the tire it fits through,

1. Type of road you drive - Highway, Country, off-road
2. Your Driving Style - Rash, Rally, Drifter, Classic
3. Weather conditions - Hot, Wet, Semi dry
4. Comfort level - Superior, good, average
5. Life -  Descent, Should last my life time, Change it once with my grocery
6. Warranty- yes - how much , no - never mind.

Small Tip: Dont just believe dealers, ask your friends which tires are they using. They don't need to have the same car because tire models they use could be available for other cars too. In the  case of tires most of them are interchangeable

Hope this helps. Have a great day :)

**Point to remember: Tyres are only point of contact for car to road, ground. Choose it wisely :) . Investing some time in research doesn't hurt you in no manner.**

Answer (score 0):

An added note to all that read this post. Your tire pressure is not the pressure indicated on the side of the tire. That is the recommended maximum tire pressure at maximum load for that tire. Your recommended tire pressure is normally noted on the door jam of drives side door.